# Azure web site - URL Rewrite using web.config not working

Tags: url, azure, web-config, url-rewriting

We are migrating some sites over to Azure and I have it setup as a "Web Site".

An example of what we're trying to do is pretty straight forward.

Current URL: http://www.website.com/Products.aspx
Clean URL: http://www.website.com/Products/

So in the web.config, there is the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ProductList">
                <match url="/Products.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/Products" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This was generated in IIS. I have tried to set the stopProcess attribute to true... which is a solution that I've seen in a few threads, but nothing is working.

This website is one of our legacy sites that uses an ISAPI module for Rewrites. Since we aren't using an Azure VM, we cannot continue using this method to rewrite.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Azure Web Sites does not have the URL Rewrite module installed, so the config approach won't work.  Maybe you could update the site code to use ASP.NET URL routing, as described in this blog post by Scott Gu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx</s>

Azure Web Sites didn't used to have the URL Rewrite Module installed, but now it does, so you can just use the standard `<system.webServer><rewrite>` section in your `web.config`.

Comment: Yikes! If this is the case, it looks like I'll be going the VM route with these sites. I have 100+ sites that we're looking to put on Azure. I figured if we kept them as "Web Site" instances, they'd be easier to manage and be more self contained rather than a bunch of sites running on IIS in a VM.

All of these sites are on old architecture. Our new architecture is fully supported on Azure... unfortunately we can't migrate the codebase. 

Thank you for your response.